# What is the suggested implementation in material design for on screen hints?

Tags: material-design

How should help items or first time help popups be styled or integrated into material design app? It seems that google has done views wedged between the toolbar and the app content, is there a particular style or functionality that is suggested? If there is I haven't seen it addressed.

Comment: read this link : https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Comment: That link is to the Material Design spec, it doesn't address help in anyway way, hence my question and referring to some of the implementation I've seen.